# Splitting the representation of $\mathbb{R}$ on $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ into irreducibles.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, complex-analysis, representation-theory, proof-explanation

On p2 of [these notes](http://math.stanford.edu/~conrad/JLseminar/Notes/L1.pdf), the author writes that the translation action of $\mathbb{R}$ on $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ is a reducible representation which does not contain any irreducible subrepresentations. Presumably by $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ he means the square integrable functions $f : \mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$.

"Indeed, for any measurable set $S\subset\mathbb{R}$, the space of functions $f$ for which the Fourier transform $\hat{f}$ has support in $S$ is a proper closed invariant subspace."

This space is certainly invariant - how would one see that it is closed?

"By Schur's lemma, any irreducible subrepresentation $W\subset L^2(\mathbb{R})$ would have dimension 1, ie $W = \langle F\rangle$ where $F: \mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ is a function such that $F(x+r)$ is proportional to $F(x)$. Thus, $F(x)$ is proportional to $e^{\lambda x}$ for some $\lambda\in\mathbb{C}$, but no such function lies in $L^2$"

No issues with this.

"However, a representation "decomposes" into a (possibly uncountable) number of irreducibles. This is the theory of "unitary disintegration""

This is my main question - what does he mean by this? Googling "unitary disintegration" did not yield any relevant results. Furthermore, how can a representation decompose into irreducibles, but have no irreducible subrepresentations?

References would be appreciated.

Comment: I would look at the representation $\pi : \mathbb{R} \to \mathcal{L}(C^1(\mathbb{R}))$, $\pi(a) f(x) = f(x+a)$. Since $\mathbb{R}$ is an abelian group the irreducible subrepresentations are of dimension $1$, thus they are eigenfunctions of all the $\pi(a), a \in \mathbb{R}$ thus of the infinitesial generator $\lim_{a \to 0} \frac{\pi(a)-\pi(0)}{a} = \frac{d}{dx}$, thus given by the complex exponentials $e^{zx}$. When restricting to $C^1(\mathbb{R}) \cap L^2(\mathbb{R})$ you don't have any such eigenfunctions anymore but only approximate eigenvalues / eigenfunctions.

Comment: And to really decompose $\pi$ onto those eigenspaces you need the Fourier or Laplace transform, depending which function space you are considering the definition will be different (Fourier transform of distributions). Projecting on the band-limited functions mentioned in your question leads to a decomposition in term of a projection valued measure

Comment: The term should be "direct integral of representations". Under this term you should be able to find references.

Answer (score 2):

Since the Fourier transform is an isometry, your only question is: why the subspace of $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ of functions that are zero on a measurable subset $A$ of $\mathbb{R}$ is a closed subspace of $L^2(\mathbb{R})$. You can express the condition as
$$(\int_A |f^2(t)| dt)^{1/2} = 0$$

The Fourier transform realizes an isomorphism between the translation representation of $\mathbb{R}$ on $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ and the representation given by multiplication by exponentials. So the Fourier transform diagonalizes the regular representation. This happens for every group ( think how one diagonalizes circular matrices).

Back to our representation of $\mathbb{R}$ on $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ by 
$$(s, f(t)) \mapsto e^{i st} \cdot f(t)$$

Since for every $A\subset \mathbb{R}$ so that $\mu(A)$, $\mu(\mathbb{R}\backslash(A)) > 0$ we can write a unitary decomposition
$$L^{2}(\mathbb{R})=L^2(A) \oplus L^2(\mathbb{R}\backslash A)$$ we may think it's enough to decompose $\mathbb{R}$ into ultimate measurable pieces and have a decomposition into irreducible. The problem is that $\mathbb{R}$ does not decompose into atoms. We can still write this representation as an integral of $1$-dimensional representations. But in our case, it is exactly considering a function as composed of all its values ( more or less). The integral of representations formalizes this thing.

Comment: My understanding is that on this occasion the regular representation is simply the representation by translations. I also agree with you that The Fourier transform establishes an isomorphism between the translation representation of $R$ on $L^2(R)$ and the representation given by multiplication by exponentials. Could you please explain what you exactly mean by saying that isomorphism is a *diagonalisation*? Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Let $G = \mathbb R$, and $V = L^2(\mathbb R)$, which is a unitary representation of $G$ with the translation action.  It is true (more generally of unitary representations of locally compact groups) that if $W \subset V$ is a subrepresentation, then there exists another subrepresentation $W'$ of $V$ such that $V = W \oplus W'$.  Consequently, $V$ is [*semisimple*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semisimple_representation) as an abstract representation of $G$: there exist irreducible subrepresentations $W_i$ of $V$ such that

$$V = \bigoplus\limits_i W_i.$$

This is an algebraic direct sum, which means for every $v \in V$, there exist unique $w_i \in W_i$, all but finitely many of which are $0$, such that $v = \sum\limits w_i$.

This is not what representation theorists who study Hilbert space representations are interested in.  They are interested, in decomposing representations into a direct sum of irreducibles in a different sense: that is, in the best case scenario they are interested in finding **closed irreducible** representations $W_i$ of $V$ (that is, closed subspaces $W_i$ of $V$ which are subrepresentations of $G$, and which themselves admit no nonzero, proper, closed  subrepresentations $W_i'$ of $W_i$) such that the $W_i$ are mutually orthogonal, and such that

$$V = \hat{\bigoplus\limits_i} W_i \tag{Hilbert space direct sum}$$
This last condition means that for every $v \in V$, there exist $w_i \in W_i$ such that $v = \sum\limits_i w_i$ (as an absolutely convergent sum in the norm topology).

This turns out to be impossible in this case, since $V = L^2(\mathbb R)$ does not have any closed, irreducible subrepresentations: if $W$ were such a subrepresentation, it would have to be one-dimensional and correspond to a unitary character of $\mathbb R$.  Then there would have to exist a function $f: \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb C$ and a real number $t$, such that

$$\int\limits_{\mathbb R} |f(x)|^2 dx < \infty$$

$$ f(x+y) = e^{ 2 \pi i ty} f(x) \tag{$x,y \in \mathbb R$}$$
and this is impossible.

Comment: Dear D_S, thank you for this good explanation. Based on what you wrote, would it be correct of me to say that the considered representation of $\mathbb R$ is reducible algebraically but irreducible topologically?

Comment: I have not heard it phrased like that but I think that's a good way to say it.

Comment: May I please ask you a very silly technical question. The translation is $(y, f(x))\mapsto f_y(x)\equiv f(x+y)$, where x is still a free variable, while y is a parameter defining the shape of the new function. 
The new function $f_y(x) \equiv f(x+y)$ can be expanded over the exponents as $ f(x+y) = \int dt e^{ixt}F(t)$, where F are its Fourier components. 
How to extract a 1-dim irreducible from this? Naively,  $f(x+y) = e^{ixt}f(t)$. But then, on the rhs, I get the free variable $t$ and no $y$. How to justify rewriting this as $f(x+y) = e^{iyt}f(x)$ ? Or, the same, $f(x+y) = e^{ixt}f(y)$ ?

Comment: In your notation you have $f(x+y) = \int dt e^{ixt}F(t)$ whereas $f(x) = \int dt e^{ixt} H(t)$ for some functions $H$ and $F$.  The connection is $F(t) = e^{iyt}H(t)$.

Comment: To put it another way, by the Fourier inversion formula we can write $$f(x) = \int dt e^{ixt}F(t)$$ for a function $F$.  That is, $f$ is the continuous sum of the one-dimensional representations $x \mapsto e^{ixt}$ over all $t$.  If we act on $f$ by translating by $y$, then each $e^{ixt}$ gets replaced by the scalar $e^{iyt}$:
$$f(x+y) = \int dt e^{iyt}F(t)e^{ixt}.$$

Comment: With this, I certainly agree: $f(x) \mapsto f(x+y)$ entails $H(t) \mapsto e^{ity} H(t)$. Through the Fourier transform, the translation representation of $\mathbb R$ on $L^2({\mathbb{R}})$ generates a representation by multiplication by exponentials. I am nevertheless missing one detail in this story: why should a decomposition of the latter representation into irreducibles render us $f(x+y)=e^{iyt}f(x)$? [I would be happy with the isomorphism $f(x+y) \longleftrightarrow e^{iyt}f(t)$, though.] I suspect that my question is silly, and I am missing something big and central in this story.

Comment: It is not true that $f(x+y) = e^{iyt}f(x)$.  The only functions $f$ that satisfy this are scalar multiples of the character $x \mapsto e^{ixt}$.  The point of the Fourier inversion formula is that an arbitrary function $f$ is a "continuous sum" of such characters.  The scalars themselves showing up in the "sum" $$f(x) = \sum\limits_{t \in \mathbb R} c_t e^{ixt}$$ (which is really an integral) are the Fourier transforms of $f$ evaluated at various $t$.

Comment: Sorry, it was a misprint of mine. I was asking about your formula $f(x+y) = e^{2\pi i t y} f(x)$. Whose meaning I am stil missing

Comment: There is no such (square integrable) function as I said in my answer.

Comment: The meaning of this is $f$ generates a one-dimensional subrepresentation of the regular representation of $\mathbb R$: acting on the function $f$ by $y$ replaces $f$ by the scalar multiple $e^{2\pi i ty}$ of $f$.

Comment: Yes, there is no such an $L^2$ function that $f(x+y)=e^{2πity}f(x)$. My question was why  the existence of a 1-dim irreducible *would* imply $f(x+y)=e^{2πity}f(x)$, for some $t\,$. I think, I now understand this. It would simply be one "term" of the Fourier expansion. Now, the very last step: why exactly isn't $f(x+y)=e^{2πity}f(x)$ an $L^2$ function? Checking this: $\int dx\,| e^{2πity}\,f(x)|^2 = \int dx\,| e^{2πity}|^2\,|\,f(x)|^2 =  \int dx|\,f(x)|^2 <\infty$. The outcome would have been different, had I have to integrate over t, but I observe no reason to do this.

Comment: OK, I have finally got it. Thank you so very much for your patience and help!

Comment: The answer mentions that "It is true (more generally of unitary representations of locally compact groups) ..." I would like to know a reference for this. Thanks in advance!